# Using Watir to click a table element

Tags: html, button, onclick, html-table, watir

JavaScript button I'd like to click although it's in a table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td height="20" align="center" nowrap style="color:#0000FF; cursor:pointer; border: 1 solid #426996; background-color: #FAFAFF;" 
      onClick="Initial();"
      onMouseOver="javascript:{style.backgroundColor='#426996'; style.color='#FFFFFF'}" 
      onMouseOut="javascript:{style.backgroundColor='#FFFFFF'; style.color='#0000FF'}">
      <font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="1"><b>&nbsp;New Incident&nbsp;</b></font>
    </td>
    <td width="4"></td>
```

There are four more "buttons" here but I'm unable to click any of them. It seem the only thing that sepearate the buttons from on another is  the `onClick` javascript event. I've tried using xpath but i just cant seem to find the element. I've tried this...

```
ie.button(:xpath => "//td[@onClick='Initial();']".exists?

ie.link(:xpath => "//td[@onClick='Initial();']".exists?
```

and they return false.

I think once this element is found i can just use the `.fire_event('onClick')` or `.click` and it should work i just can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element you are trying to click is not a button but a cell in a table. More information: http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/td

Something like this should work (not tested):

```
browser.element(:css => "td[onClick=Initial();]").click
```

More information: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#matching-attrs

Comment: Željko thanks for the quick response, when I attempted using the above: 'irb(main):026:0> ie.element(:css => "td[onClick=Initial();]").click Nokogiri::CSS::SyntaxError: unexpected 'Initial(' after 'equal' from H:/Programming/Ruby/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.5.5 -x86-mingw32/lib/nokogiri/css/parser_extras.rb:87:in `on_error' from (eval):3:in `_racc_do_parse_c' from (eval):3:in `do_parse'  ETC>>>>>>>>>>>>> I have yet to do any other searching or any other syntax. I'll be able to later but thanks again.

Comment: I also tried: ie.element(:css => "td[onClick='Initial();']").click it didn't work as well. Unable to locate the element.

Comment: For some reason when I save the page as HTML I am able to click and do what ever I want but on the "live" page I'm unable to do anything. It won't locate the elements I know can be clicked on the HTML page. Although the page is not ".html" natively it looks like "URL/Default.cfm?(some session infromation)". Any ideas?

Comment: I ended up being able to use ".element(:text, 'mytext').click" when I saved the page as html on my local computer, unfortunately this doesn't work for the live site but this is another problem to be addressed else where. Points to you @Zeljko.

Answer (score 3):

Use #td method with a regexp instead:

```
ie.td(:html => %r{Initial()}).click
```

If it's possible then assign some html ID or class attribute to your td to make the locating easier. Something in the lines of:

```
<td id="mytd" ... onClick="Initial();">...</td>
ie.td(:id => "mytd").click
```

Or use text with a regexp:

```
ie.td(:text => /New Incident/).click
```

Comment: I wish I could change the html. This would've been much easier. I'll be able to check in an hour or two from now. Thanks for you input.

Comment: I've also attempted both of these but neither could find the location for the button. This is making me mad at the people who created this site. Although by creating my own page using the html source:    ie.td(:id => "mytd").click worked. Unfortunately there's no way for me to ask the webmaster to update the code.

Comment: What does puts ie.td.html and puts ie.td.text output?

Comment: ie.td.html -> Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException: Uable to locate using..blah ie.td.text ->Same as previous ie.td -> #<Watir::TableCell:0x..f879934b6b located=fals specifiers={:tag_name=>["th","td"]}> ALSO my workaround failed.